# Does Spring AMQP support rabbitmq federation?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I know that Spring supports rabbitmq clustering through the "addresses" attribute on `<rabbit:connection-factory>`. Though does it provide support for federated rabbitmqs and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a function of clients (such as Spring AMQP); it's all done using [server-side configuration](https://www.rabbitmq.com/federation.html). So the simple answer is **yes**.